# Is there a way to use the same subprogram for multiple buttons across multiple forms in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, button, multiple-forms

I'm relatively inexperienced with programming, but have been taking it as a subject for a few years. This year is my final year of school, which means I have to undertake a major work. I've chosen the game Mastermind in VB.net, but I've encountered a problem that I haven't learnt to fix. In the main game, I need to cycle through colours by clicking the four buttons each time the person guesses. I want to reuse the code, because it isn't small, but I don't know how to do this with multiple buttons, and more specifically multiple forms. At the moment, the subprogram is in a module with the intention that it can be accessed when a second player picks a code before the game starts. This is the code I'm using to cycle through each of colours. There is another three like this to form the four buttons needed:

```
CodeSelect1()
     BackColourRed1 = True
     BackColourOrange1 = False
     BackColourYellow1 = False
     BackColourGreen1 = False
     BackColourBlue1 = False
     BackColourPurple1 = False
     If BackColourRed1 = True Then
         frm2PlayerChooseCode.btnCode1.BackgroundImage = My.Resources.Orange
         BackColourRed1 = False
         BackColourOrange1 = True
     ElseIf BackColourOrange1 = True Then
         frm2PlayerChooseCode.btnCode1.BackgroundImage = My.Resources.Yellow
         BackColourOrange1 = False
         BackColourYellow1 = True
     ElseIf BackColourYellow1 = True Then
         frm2PlayerChooseCode.btnCode1.BackgroundImage = My.Resources.Green
         BackColourYellow1 = False
         BackColourGreen1 = True
     ElseIf BackColourGreen1 = True Then
         frm2PlayerChooseCode.btnCode1.BackgroundImage = My.Resources.Blue
         BackColourGreen1 = False
         BackColourBlue1 = True
     ElseIf BackColourBlue1 = True Then
         frm2PlayerChooseCode.btnCode1.BackgroundImage = My.Resources.Purple
         BackColourBlue1 = False
         BackColourPurple1 = True
     ElseIf BackColourPurple1 = True Then
         frm2PlayerChooseCode.btnCode1.BackgroundImage = My.Resources.Red
         BackColourPurple1 = False
         BackColourRed1 = True
     End If
End Sub
```

I considered a potential solution, which I will put below, but as far as I can work out, it only works for code on the one form. I tried making the variables public, but that gave me an error. I feel as if I'm tickling the edge of what I need to do, but I just can't figure it out:

```
Public Sub CodeSelect1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) _
Handles frmEasy.btnCode1.Click, frmEasy.btnCode5.Click, btnCode9.Click, btnCode13.Click, btnCode17.Click, btnCode21.Click, btnCode25.Click, btnCode29.Click, btnCode33.Click, btnCode37.Click
    Dim myButton = DirectCast(sender, Button)
```

In summary, how do I adapt this code (or use different code entirely), to use across multiple forms?
All help is appreciated, and Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change your sub to the following, you'll be able to pass the button as a parameter to it. Then, in each button click handler in each form, just add the following code.

```
CodeSelect1(CType(sender, Button))
```

Here's the updated sub

```
Friend Sub CodeSelect1(btn As Button)
    BackColourRed1 = True
    BackColourRed1 = False
    BackColourYellow1 = False
    BackColourYellow1 = False
    BackColourBlue1 = False
    BackColourPurple1 = False
    If BackColourRed1 Then
        btn.BackgroundImage = My.Resources.Orange
        BackColourRed1 = False
        BackColourOrange1 = True
    ElseIf BackColourOrange1 Then
        btn.BackgroundImage = My.Resources.Yellow
        BackColourOrange1 = False
        BackColourYellow1 = True
    ElseIf BackColourYellow1 Then
        btn.BackgroundImage = My.Resources.Green
        BackColourYellow1 = False
        BackColourGreen1 = True
    ElseIf BackColourGreen1 Then
        btn.BackgroundImage = My.Resources.Blue
        BackColourGreen1 = False
        BackColourBlue1 = True
    ElseIf BackColourBlue1 Then
        btn.BackgroundImage = My.Resources.Purple
        BackColourBlue1 = False
        BackColourPurple1 = True
    ElseIf BackColourPurple1 Then
        btn.BackgroundImage = My.Resources.Red
        BackColourPurple1 = False
        BackColourRed1 = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks so much David, I think that has solved my issue. You have no idea how much I've been tearing my hair out over this. I've just got to implement it now, but I'm pretty sure it's going to work!

Answer (score 0):

Send the button1-button5 as parameters to your function. ParamArray would be handy.

btw instead of this IsTrue-joke

```
If BackColourRed1 = True Then
```

you should use

```
If BackColourRed1 Then
```

And your life would be much easier if you use some `BackColor As Color` variable so you don't have to reivent the weel.

Comment: Thanks Pavlinll, your suggestion for the colours is a good idea, I'll take it into account